# Change in behavior in BindingSource between .Net Framework 3.5 and 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, bindingsource

We are upgrading our application from .Net Framework 3.5 to 4.0 and we have come across a change in behavior with BindingSource.

The code:

```
bindingSource.DataSource = new Dictionary<int, int>( 0 );
```

in .Net Framework 3.5 does NOT issue the PositionChanged event. However when compiled against .Net Framework 4.n it does get fired.
When checking the current item in the PositionChanged event it holds the dictionary itself.

Is this a bug in .Net Framework 4.n? Below are some tests that highlight the behavior:

```
[TestMethod]
public void FW40_WhenBindingToEmptyCollectionThenPositionChangedIsInvoked() {
    Dictionary<int, int> emptyCollection = new Dictionary<int, int>( 0 );

    BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
    object currentItem = null;

    bindingSource.PositionChanged += ( sender, e ) => {
        currentItem = ( (BindingSource)sender ).CurrencyManager.Current;
    };

    bindingSource.DataSource = emptyCollection;

    Assert.AreEqual<Type>( typeof( Dictionary<int, int> ), currentItem.GetType() );
}

[TestMethod]
public void FW35_WhenBindingToEmptyCollectionThenPositionChangedIsNotInvoked() {
    Dictionary<int, int> emptyCollection = new Dictionary<int, int>( 0 );

    BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
    object currentItem = null;
    bindingSource.PositionChanged += ( sender, e ) => {
        currentItem = ( (BindingSource)sender ).CurrencyManager.Current;
    };
    bindingSource.DataSource = emptyCollection;

    Assert.IsNull( currentItem );
}

[TestMethod]
public void FWAll_WhenBindingToNonEmptyCollectionThenPositionChangedIsInvokedAndCurrentItemIsKeyValuePair() {
    Dictionary<int, int> noneEmptyCollection = new Dictionary<int, int> { { 1, 1 } };

    BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
    object currentItem = null;
    bindingSource.PositionChanged += ( sender, e ) => {
        currentItem = ( (BindingSource)sender ).CurrencyManager.Current;
    };
    bindingSource.DataSource = noneEmptyCollection;

    Assert.AreEqual<Type>( typeof( KeyValuePair<int, int> ), currentItem.GetType() );
}
```

Comment: I would expect a `PositionChanged` event when the data source has changed only if it results in a change to the `Position` property. `Current` being a reference to the entire data source sounds like a separate bug. I wasn't aware of these changes, and can't find anything about it in their documentation